# How to Enable Integration features on a Virtual XP Mode connected to a domain

Tags: windows-xp-mode, windows-domain

I have the Virtual XP Mode running on my Windows 7 x64 since quite a while and never had a real problem. Just when I added the Virtual XP Mode to our domain (my host PC has always been on the domain) the integration features stopped working. Basically here is what happened:

- It all of a sudden asked me for a login for XPMUser which I never had to put a password in for
- It would not let me log in with my domain credentials saying the "You are not allowed to logon interactively"
- After disabling the integration features I could log in with my domain credentials - no problem

So, how do I get the integration features to work with the virtual machine being on the domain? Do our IT guys have to set some special policies on the domain controller if yes: which)?

I have shared a folder for now so I can exchange some data with my host PC but it would be nice to get the clipboard sharing again - it's a rather useful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it got fixed by granting my domain user admin rights on the VirtualXP setup.